# Why StreamProvider is getting called multiple times in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class FooPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final asyncValue = ref.watch(sp);
    print('loading = ${asyncValue.isLoading}, value = ${asyncValue.valueOrNull}');
    return Container();
  }
}

final sp = StreamProvider<int>((ref) async* {
  yield 0;
});
```

**Output:**

```
flutter: loading = true, value = null
flutter: loading = false, value = 0
flutter: loading = false, value = 0
```

What called it, or why the line `flutter: loading = false, value = 0` is repeated two times?

Comment: That message is from build, which can be executed 60 times per second if there's an animation nearby.  The important thing is that loading = true eventually became loading = false, and that happened precisely once, so everything is working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the StreamProvider doesn't get called multiple times, your build method does.

if you change your provider to

```dart
final sp = StreamProvider<int>((ref) async* {
  print('provider called');
  yield 0;
});
```

This does not get called more than once.

Build method can get called many times, and `ref.watch` there will give you the same instance of provider unles it was changed or invalidated since the last build.